# Unable to find UI designer in the new Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have downloaded the new android studio that has been released recently. I am unable to find the UI design preview for the xml, as it is in eclipse. Any help or suggestions on that?

Comment: What happened when you Googled for this, or checked the online help, or the Jetbrains Knowledge Base?

Comment: were u successful in getting the UI?

Comment: I was trying to suggest that SO is not the best, or correct place to ask simple "how do I" questions on an unreleased, unsupported product.  View->Tool Windows.  Please take the time to learn the menu structure and window system of IDEA rather than ask a question every time you can't find something.  The online help is also very good.

Comment: `This is NOT a user issue...this is a BUG in the software!`

I have found a way to access it, however, it is very annoying because it can ONLY be viewed in landscape mode....in the Preview tab!

I just installed Android Studio 0.2.7 and was not able to get to the UI designer (Palette), after some playing around, I was able to. 1) switch `State` to landscape, or 2) under "Configuration to render this layout with the IDE" in the preview tab (next to the device render option!), and create a new portrait orientation configuration

Comment: > "What happened when you Googled for this?"

You now get this stack overflow question, I'm glad it got answered.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Open a xml layout file:

- at the bottom, you have two tabs: Design/Text [image]
- in design mode, you see the preview directly
- in text mode, the preview is (by default) on the right, toggled by a 'Preview' button in the rightmost bar

[image]

You can also show/hide it with View > Tool Windows > Preview

**EDIT**

*Attention*: the IDE only displays the preview if editing a layout file in the res/layout* directory of an Android project. In particular, it won't be displayed if editing a file in build/res/layout* since those are not source directory but output directory.

The Resource folder is set automatically, and can be viewed (and changed) in Project Structure > Modules > [Module name] > Android > Resources directory.

Comment: there are no tabs at the bottom. I tried the View > Tool Windows , it also doesn't have the Preview option. I there something wrong with my ide?

Comment: Probably an issue with the file you are editing; is it an android layout file?

Comment: the file has to be activity_main.xml right?\

Comment: The name isn't relevant. But the file should be in a layout*/ folder in the res directory of your project. Check the configuration of the project folders in `Project Structure > Facets > Android > Resources Directory`

Comment: ... of an Android project?

Comment: yes exactly of an android project.

Comment: i suppose i got it. I was in the build/res/all/debug/layout but the design view came when i used the same file name from src/main/res/layout. Thanks for so much help. I got a bit confused on that.

Comment: i also had the same problem. I can't find the 'Design' tab. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jomia see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660039/where-is-android-studio-layout-preview/16669780#16669780

Comment: @etienne Thanks for the tips.. Now i can see the design tab

Comment: I had this problem from a fresh install and new project created by the wizard. No tabs. Close file, re-open (wasn't in recent files!) from project pane, and now it has Design/Text tabs. Buggier than Eclipse!

Comment: This worked for me; sure would've been nice if `View => Tool Windows => Designer` weren't disabled even though clearly the designer was NOT visible. :/