# Android Studio - Need to edit Manifest, Menu XML files manually

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android studio. Unlike eclipse with ADT plugin, in Android studio I end up manually writing full XMLs for menus, manifest files etc. I am not getting the GUI to enter values so that it will automatically populate XML files. Only text view view is getting displayed. I believe there should be a plugin or a way similar to eclipse GUI to edit these files.

I spent enough time searching for it but could not find anything useful.Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I looking for a better way to edit XML files in android studio

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16644947/833647

Comment: Yeahh... I agree with @KenWolf

Comment: KenWolf link shows how to edit layout files only :(

Comment: @KenWolf Any thoughts??

Comment: what exact features you are looking for?

Comment: mmm.... if you need edit your `xml` files... click them two times... then `Android Studio` will open automatically his editor...

Comment: Really i'm so confused with that question...

Comment: Edited the question.. I need GUI to edit menu and manifest files.

Comment: put your cursor on that field where u wants to edit and press ctrl + space. by it automatic suggestions comes up

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma So is that the only solution? Eclipse with ADT is very flexible to edit XMLs. Isn't it?

Comment: There is a preview button on the right hand side, click on that to see the preview while editing the xml files.

Comment: I am not looking for preview :(

Comment: Learn to write an intellij plugin if you NEED this feature, otherwise learn to do it by hand.

Comment: Then your question is poorly worded. Nobody knows what you need. Post some details or... I don't know, Search on google.

Comment: what u exactly want..please elaborate. we r so confused.

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma do not use abbreviations here on `StackOverFlow` please, people who speak another languages could not understand you.

Comment: @Aspicas I elaborated..Could you try to understand question now?

Comment: Click two times the `TextView` element then to edit `text or id` for example. You can use `CTRL + B` on any object to `go to Declaration`.

Comment: @Aspicas mmm. Thanks for your try..

Comment: You understood my question entirely different :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93171/discussion-between-bhargav-kumar-r-and-aspicas).